# How to change current screen in kivy after playing video

Tags: python, kivy

My app have a button>click on button will start playing a video>after video finishes, i want to navgate to final screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import webbrowser
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer
import time

Builder.load_string('''
<MenuScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        padding: 5
        spacing: 5
        cols: 1
        padding: root.width*0.1
        Button:
            background_normal: ''
            background_color:(0.862, 0.078, 0.235, 0.9)
            text: 'PLAY'
            font_size: '20sp'
            on_press: root.manager.current='vdo'
            on_press: root.val1()
<Vdo>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        VideoPlayer:
            id: testid
            state: 'stop'
            source: 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm'
            fullscreen: True
            image_play: 'black.png'
            image_stop: 'black.png'
            image_pause: 'black.png'
            image_volumehigh: 'black.png'
            image_volumelow: 'black.png'
            image_volumemedium: 'black.png'
            image_volumemuted: 'black.png'
<Final>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: 'over'

''')

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def val1(self):
        print "1 is executed"
        vdo.ids.testid.state='play'
        sm.current='final'

class Vdo(Screen):
    def val2(self):
        print "i am executed"

class Final(Screen):
    def val3(self):
        print "i am executed"

sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu)
vdo = Vdo(name='vdo')
sm.add_widget(vdo)
final = Final(name='final')
sm.add_widget(final)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

My code do not move to final screen after video finishes. I tried give time sleep after video play but during that time video will play in background.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to bind a function to the VideoPlayer state property so that when is fire you will check if position==duration (the end) and move to the next screen

```
<Vdo>:
    video: testid #easier to access this way
    VideoPlayer:
        id: testid
        state: 'stop'
        source: 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm'
        fullscreen: True
        image_play: 'black.png'
        image_stop: 'black.png'
        image_pause: 'black.png'
        image_volumehigh: 'black.png'
        image_volumelow: 'black.png'
        image_volumemedium: 'black.png'
        image_volumemuted: 'black.png'
```

in your python code:

```
def state_change(instance, value):
    if vdo.video.duration == vdo.video.position:
        sm.current = 'final'
vdo.video.state.bind(state_change)
```

I hope this will help